# Append byte array to StringBuilder

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, arrays, stringbuilder

I am trying append byte array to string builder, but not getting the result.

I have to return it to the **web service** in the form of **byte array**.

See my code below:

```
WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)image1.Source);
wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 400, 400, 0, 100);
bytearray = ms.ToArray();
```

Now I am appending byte array to string builder.

```
StringBuilder stb1 = new StringBuilder();
stb1.Append("<image>");
for (int i = 0; i < bytearray.Length; i++)
{
    stb1.Append(bytearray[i]);
}
stb1.Append("</image>");
```

XML String looks like this:

```
 StringBuilder stb1 = new StringBuilder();

            stb1.Append("<Title>");
            stb1.Append("</Title>");
            stb1.Append("<image>");
            stb1.Append("</image>");
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: @Lennart the web service will return "Success" message, but the problem is "How to append Byte[] to String Builder". Thanks

Comment: `Cast` yout byte to a `char` like `stb1.Append((char)bytearray[i]);`

Comment: @Sybren I tested your code, but its giving me some ununderstandable language in response. Thanks

Comment: @NiteshKothari what is the response and what is the response you're expecting?

Comment: @Sybren I am getting this response: <image>ÿØÿà</image>

Comment: Should it convert to text in hex form? or base 64? or what?

Comment: try converting your byte[] to base64 string and send it like that

Comment: You can't just append a bunch of single bytes to a UTF16 string and expect it to work properly. You need to append text, not binary data.

Comment: @weston I have to send this "XMLString" to web service in byte array form. Thanks!!

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic yes, I know it, but restriction is "Byte Array" form. thanks

Comment: Problem is you need a string. So you need to specify the string representation format of the byte array. Is there any documentation you can link to and we'll help interpret it.

Answer (score 3):

Having so little informations it's hard to give some useful response. It looks like you're trying to push some image in HTML/XML-like format. In that case probably you should just convert your binary into Base64 string:

```
var byteString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

But if your web service requires it to be the raw byte array, then you shouldn't use string builder in the first place.

Comment: But I have to return it in byte array form. @Horusiath

Comment: So why you're using `StringBuilder`? You should describe a little more about what is expected format of input and output of the web service.

Comment: Ohh yes, I am really sorry about it. please help me brother. Thanks @Horusiath